# About some text styling in css with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, css

I am coding a google maps page and I'm trying to style the scroll bar.
The strange thing is that every text is being underlined, but I don't want that to happen (I mean, I don't want underline except the last line with the url, it most probably be some silly thing to fix, but I really can't find it, can you please help me?
Here is the live site: [www.gsilvainc.com/jewels/test.php](http://www.gsilvainc.com/jewels/test.php)
And this is the code i'm using so far:

```
<?php include("dbinfo.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">

#side_bar {
font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#000000;


}
 #side_bar A:link {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
#side_bar A:visited {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
#side_bar A:active {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
#side_bar A:hover { color: red;}


#side_bar   A.clase2:visited {font-size:12;color:#0000cc;} 
#side_bar   A.clase2:active {font-size:12;color:#0000cc;} 
#side_bar   A.clase2:link {font-size:12;color:#0000cc;} 
#side_bar   A.clase2:hover {font-size:12;color:#0000cc;}


</style>


<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=<?php   echo $key; ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onunload="GUnload()">


<!-- you can use tables or divs for the overall layout -->
<table border=0>
  <tr> <td width = 200 valign="top" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #4444ff;">
       <!-- =========== side_bar with scroll bar ================= -->
       <div id="side_bar"  style="overflow:auto; height:450px;"></div>
       <!-- ===================================================== -->
    </td>
    <td>
       <div id="map" style="width: 550px; height: 450px"></div>
    </td>

  </tr>
  </table>



 <script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[

 if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
  var side_bar_html = "";
  var gmarkers = [];
  var htmls = [];
  var i = 0;


  // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
  function createMarker(point,name,html, address, city, state, zip, phone, url) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point);
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
    });
    gmarkers[i] = marker;
    htmls[i] = html;
    side_bar_html += '<b><a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + name + '<\/a><\/b><\/br>'+ address + '<\/br>' + city +', '+ state +', '+ zip +'<\/br>' + phone +'<br \/><a class="clase2" href="http://'+url+'">'+url+'<\/a><br \/><hr \/>';
    i++;
    return marker;
   }

   function myclick(i) {
    gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[i]);
   }

    // create the map
   var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
   map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
   map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
   map.setCenter(new GLatLng( 41.907787,-90.359741), 9);


  // Read the data from 100.xml

   GDownloadUrl("phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=41&lng=-90&radius=5000", function (doc) {
    var xmlDoc = GXml.parse(doc);
    var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      // obtain the attribues of each marker
      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new GLatLng(lat,lng);
      var html = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var label = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var city = markers[i].getAttribute("city");
      var state = markers[i].getAttribute("state");
      var zip = markers[i].getAttribute("zip");
      var phone = markers[i].getAttribute("phone");
      var url = markers[i].getAttribute("url");
      // create the marker
      var marker = createMarker(point,label,html,address, city, state, zip, phone, url);
      map.addOverlay(marker);
    }
    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
  });
}

else {
  alert("Sorry, the Google Maps API is not compatible with this browser");
}

// This Javascript is based on code provided by the
// Community Church Javascript Team
// http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
// http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

//]]>
</script>
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your td tag has "text-decoration: underline; " in it, which is being inherited. Make

```
<td width = 200 valign="top" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #4444ff;">
```

into

```
<td width = 200 valign="top" style="border-bottom:1px solid #4444ff; color: #4444ff;">
```

Assuming that you want to have a border under the cell.

If you aren't already using it, the Firebug plugin for Firefox is incredibly useful for viewing where styles are being inherited from.